# Trouble with Rspec for timestamp in hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

To compare to hashdata we had this in our spec

```
it 'should return the rec_1 in page format' do
     expect(response_body_json).to eql(Preseneter.new(ActiveRecordObject).page)
end
```

Presenter is a class that will accept the ActiveRecordObject and respond with hash data in a particular format.

**We then added updated_at with timestamp to the hash_data.**
In my code I have `updated_at = Time.zone.now`
So the spec started failing because both the updated_at had difference of few seconds.

Tried stubbing Time.zone

```
it 'should return the rec_1 in page format' do
     allow(Time.zone).to receive(:now).and_return('hello')
     expect(response_body_json).to eql(Preseneter.new(ActiveRecordObject).page)
end
```

but now response_body_json.updated_at comes as 'hello'
but still Right hand side comes with a timestamp

Where am I going wrong???
or is there any other better way to handle such scenarios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't shown how `response_body_json` nor `Presenter#page` are defined, I cannot really answer why your current attempt doesn't work.

However, I can instead say that I would use a different approach.

There are two standard ways to write tests like this:

1. **Freeze time**.

Assuming you're using a relatively up-to-date rails version, you can use use [`ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers#freeze_time`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-freeze_time%60) somewhere in the test, e.g. something like:

```
around do |example|
  freeze_time { example.run }
end

it 'should return the movie_1 in page format' do
  expect(response_body_json).to eql(Presenter.new(ActiveRecordObject).page)
end
```

If you're on an older rails version, you may need to use `travel_to(Time.zone.now)` instead.

And if you're on a very old rails version (or a non-rails project!), which doesn't have this helper library, you can use [`timecop`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) instead.

2. **Use a fuzzy matcher for timestamps** (e.g. [`be_within`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher)). Something along the lines of:

.

```
it 'should return the movie_1 in page format' do
  expected_json = Presenter.new(ActiveRecordObject).page
  expect(response_body_json).to match(
    expected_json.merge(updated_at: be_within(3.seconds).of(Time.zone.now))
  )
end
```

Comment: this is my rails version  5.0.1
Tried adding freeze_time
getting this error  ' undefined method `freeze_time'  '

Comment: NoMethodError:
       undefined method `freeze_time' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApiV2SomeController::GETIndex:0x007f94275d27e0>
       Did you mean?  freeze

Comment: When I tried the second way 

 "updatedAt"=>"2018-11-28T15:12:01.408+05:30", :updatedAt=>(be within 3 of 2018-11-28 15:12:01 +0530)

this is how the data goes.

Comment: @Surya `freeze_time` was added to Rails 5.2. As I wrote above, you can use `travel_to(Time.zone.now)` -- that's literally the same thing, just slightly more clunky.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "the second way". Are you saying that it worked? Or that it failed? If it failed, then what's the error? Is the issue that you're comparing a string with a time object?

Comment: Ya in my 
LHS I get this  -"updatedAt" => (be within 3 of 2018-11-28 18:46:45 +0530),
RHS I get this  +"updatedAt" => "2018-11-28T18:46:45.154+05:30",

think like to eql 
be_within could be given 
not sure if be within could be used as mentioned in the answer

Comment: But travel_to worked. I had to include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
before do
  movie_1.publish
  allow(Time.zone).to receive(:now).and_return(Time.now)
  get :show, format: :json, params: { id: movie_1.uuid }
end

it 'should return the rec_1 in page format' do
 expect(response_body_json).to eql(Preseneter.new(ActiveRecordObject).page)
end
```

end

The above code resolved my issue.

Looks like I have given this `allow(Time.zone).to receive(:now).and_return('hello')` in the wrong place. It  should be placed within the before block so that it gets set before the test case is run and I guess it must probably be set before the get request as well.

However Tom Lord's approach is a better approach.